Metal monocrystalline structures and tempering
This may come off as more of a fantasy/worldbuilding question, but I believe there is real science to this, so I'm asking it here.

Pre-question information/my current understanding.

As is widely known, metals (any many other materials, but this is specifically referring to metals, e.g iron/steel) exhibit crystalline structures throughout in the form of grains, seperated by boundaries, and often including exclusions and many other oddities in the structure. The size, shape, layout, and many other properties of these grains has a considerable impact on the macro-scale properties of the metal, e.g it's toughness, rigidness, tensile strength, hardness, and all the other wonderful properties of metals.
As I understand it, particularly in high-end aerospace applications, such as turbofan turbine blades, it's a known (if not necessarily common) practice to produce the turbine blades not with forging, but with a process reminiscent of casting, where the parts are kept at just above melting temperature, and then very slowly cooled with a probe at a specific point, with the end result being a single crystal that grows from the probe point, and is perfectly continuous throughout the entire part, with the end result being a part that is exceptionally rigid, presumably incredibly hard, and has remarkably low thermal expansion, which is critical for minimising tolerances in order to improve efficiency of the overall machine.

The question (a.k.a the tl;dr).

If you have a cast part which has been produced using the method described above to create a part which is perfectly monocrystalline, is there any need/value in tempering, annealing, edge hardening, etc? (My gut instinct is no, since there's no grains to modify, but I'm not experienced enough to trust my gut on this).
Also, is it 'safe' to machine these parts, such as cutting/turning/sanding, etc, such that it won't negatively impact the monocrystalline structure?

Single crystal is often more brittle than amorphous, meaning XTAL may far worse under vibrations. But it might be harder.  It depends on the material and crystal phase (for example, Carbon crystal - Graphite being fairly soft whereas Diamond being hard, both being Carbon crystals).  I am not sure but I suspect it's more common to control crystal gain size to give some optimum mix of flexibility and stiffness.

It gives only a minimal overview, but at least one paper says heat treatment is done:

2.2.3. Heat Treatment
In order to optimize their microstructure and properties, the SX turbine blades are subjected to post-process heat treatments, which include homogenization, solutionizing, and aging and can vary depending on chemical composition, fabrication routes, and intended service conditions [4,37]. Homogenization, which is designed to produce recrystallized grain structures, and solutionizing, which is designed to dissolve age-hardening constituents and carbides into solid solution, are both high-temperature processes. Both are followed by aging, which is performed at intermediate temperatures to drive precipitation of a dispersed phase throughout the matrix to develop maximum strength [4,37]. These heat treatment procedures occur after the investment mold and ceramic cores have been removed. As with the developments of the SX turbine blades, their heat treatment procedures have also become complicated. Currently, there is a significant amount of interest in developing heat treatment procedures that require less time and energy. A recent US Department of Energy report estimates the energy usage of metal heat treatment in the US to be in the order of 270 TBTU [38]. The current heat treatment processes. that consist of solution treatment and aging, require ~22 h for stress relief, solution treatment, and aging process. To reduce the heat treatment cycle time and temperature, an in-depth understanding of the thermodynamics and the kinetics of the precipitate evolution process is necessary.

As the paper itself says, however, it's difficult to find much in the way of solid information or (especially) details about the processing involved.
Reference
https://www.mdpi.com/2504-4494/4/4/101
